# Matrix change of basis: where can it lead?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-calculus, change-of-basis

Consider a positive-semidefinite Hermitian matrix $A$ of dimension $d\times d$. I would like to know, is it always possible to find a change of basis resulting in a matrix $B$ where the diagonal is a constant?
Namely, $B=UAU^\dagger$ with $U$ invertible has $B_{ii}=c$.

If in general such a $U$ does not exist, for which $A$ does it?

P.S. I hope my question is well posed, otherwise I can make edits to state the problem more precisely and concretely.

EDIT 1: what if $U^\dagger U = 1$ ?

Comment: Do you want your $U$ to be unitary or just invertible? This is important information that you should have added.

Comment: That's correct, maybe I just ask $U$ to be invertible, and in case be interested if it can also be unitary.

Comment: Just to be sure: what do you mean by $U^\dagger$? If its the adjoint (conjugate transpose), then you only get a basis change if $U$ is unitary

Comment: conjugate transpose, but maybe it's enough to consider real $U$

Comment: Then it's not a change of basis, unless $U$ is unitary

Comment: I do not require to have orthonormal bases

Comment: @amsmath It is a change of basis if you associated $A$ with a skew-linear form instead of a linear transformation

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. In particular, see [corollary 5 of this document](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ewkahan/MathH110/trace0.pdf).